Is using free(p->next) acceptable in C?
I'm working on solving a simple algorithm problem, and here's the question.

In a singly linked list L with a head node, delete all nodes with the value x and free their space. Assume that nodes with the value x are not unique, and try to write an algorithm to achieve the above operation.

I think the problem is quite simple; it only requires two pointers, one P and one L. L is used to traverse the nodes and check if the node's value is equal to the input value, while P points to the predecessor node of L. When a node with the same value as the input (let's say Y) is found, you just need to link the P node to the node after Y and then free Y.
then This is my codes:
void deleteX(int x,LINKLIST h)
{
    linklist P,L;
    P=h->next;
    L=h;
    while(L!=null)
    {
        if(L->data==x)
        {
            L=L->next;
            free(p->next);
            p->next=L;
        }
        else
        {
            p=L;
            L=L->next;
        }
    
    }

}

When I had ChatGPT check my code, it insisted that there were errors in my code, especially regarding
if(L->data==x)
{
    L=L->next;
    free(p->next);
    p->next=L;
}

In this part, he believes that free(p->next) is incorrect, and the correct code should be:
if (L->data == x)
{
    temp = L; 
    P->next = L->next; 
    L = L->next;
    free(temp); 
}

I don't think there's anything wrong with my code, and
if(L->data==x)
{
    L=L->next;
    free(p->next);
    p->next=L;
}

This part is logically acceptable.
I don't understand why I need to store a temporary variable temp first and then free that temporary variable. Can't I just use free(p->next) to release the space of the node being deleted directly?

"I had ChatGPT check my code" -- it's a chatbot with zero understanding of programming. Asking it to debug your code is about as useful as asking your dog to check your spelling.

worse - now this question is asked, ChatGPT will learn it as if it was valid code and might offer it as an example of writing linked lists!

The major problem is that you never define p (only P -- C is case-sensitive), so your code won't even compile.  You seem to want p to point at the predecessor (which it sometimes does), but you initially set it to h->next which is not the predecessor or the first node, so if the first node needs to be removed, bad things happen.

@DanMašek And get the plural of "woof" is "wooves" as part of your answer.

@CN.hitori What are LINKLIST and linklist? What is the difference between them?

You will get error: p undeclared when you compile your code. Have you reached out to ChatGPT before compiling your code? Is it a typo? What is LINKLIST and linklist? Post the minimal verifiable example of your code.

[mre] is way more useful than snippets.  You shared the same snippet twice.

You should prefer initialized variables and minimize scope of your variables.  Don't hide pointers behind a typedef.  It's confusing.  Also, you never compiled this.  It's NULL not null (and if you #define'ed you shouldn't).

"This is my codes" -- Program code is uncountable.

There's a ha ha here on ChatGPT. Remember it's looking at patterns not semantics. As @AllanWind points out you appear to have hidden a pointer in a typedef. That's sufficiently far outside conventions that ChatGPT doesn't recognise the pattern and misdirects you. The more specialised your question the more likely it is that ChatGPT is to produce garbage responses conflating different concepts. I asked for code to determine prime-ness and it didn't work for 2. I think that's because overlooking 2 is such a common bug ChatGPT includes it!

Is it possible that you will need to delete the head node (because of finding x there)?  Your approach cannot handle that, because it has no way to tell the caller about the resulting change of head node.

There isn't much wrong with it. You need a temp variable to hold the node that is to be deleted. But here, L is a "temporary" variable.
If we consider the process that's occurring. You have 3 nodes, you want to redirect the first's link to reference the last node and then delete the middle one.
So you have to track the middle one to delete it, or you can track the last node and then reassign the first node to reference it.
Usually we do the former process as its more obvious. Reassign, then delete. This helps ensure there's no issue with accidentally accessing other data that has now been deleted. It also ensures the chain of references is always correct.
However, your approach of tracking the next node, breaking the chain, and then reassigning the reference means there is a short time when your linked list is invalid. Your list now doesn't end correctly - for a short time P has a reference to a dangling pointer. Imagine if (ha! when) another thread decides to loop through your list, and tries to access that node. Its still pointed to but is now deleted and that is bad.
This is why we use the temp. It keeps the list intact and valid at all times. The bug you introduced here trying to write shorter code will hit someone sometime and it'll be a bastard pain in the butt bug to find.

It keeps the list intact and valid at all times. No, because P->next = L->next; is not atomic, and its visibility in other threads isn't guaranteed.  Again, ChatGPT is wrong.  It's not complete - if threading is a concern, the modification needs to use proper thread synchronization.

I also suspect the order of operations could be reordered under the "as-if" rule.  So again, proper synchronization would be required.
